# CheckedListBox checked items to object conversion?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a collection named Subjects with attributes as Name in string, and SubjectCode in int. I passed it to a checked list box. On the press of a button, i want to get the collection of all the items checked by user, convert it as the collection Subjects.

Plz anyone could help....

Thnx in advance...

Comment: Code speaks louder than words...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CheckedListBox can store any kind of class object.  You just need a ToString() override that shows the description of the object.  For example:

```
    class Subject {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public override string ToString() { return Name; }
    }
```

You can add these to the Items collection.  Reading back the selected ones just takes casting the object back to Subject.  For example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Subject { Name = "Hans", Code = 42 });
        checkedListBox1.Items.Add(new Subject { Name = "User", Code = 486196 });
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var selected = new List<Subject>();
        foreach (int index in checkedListBox1.SelectedIndices) {
            selected.Add((Subject)checkedListBox1.Items[index]);
        }
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hans, as usual you've provided concise and detailed instructions (I Had missed the "ToString")

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Subject[] myObjects;

void onButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      foreach (int i in this.checkedItems.CheckedIndecies)
      { 
           Subject obj = myObjects[i];
      }
}
```

You can directly access the objects, but you risk the scenario where the objects in the listBox aren't of type subject, and it gives you more extendability in the future.